# in haml & serve, repeat elements or block several times

Tags: ruby, haml

I'm using haml with serve to primarily rapid prototype html documents. I'd like to be efficient and repeat a block of code several times.

E.g. i would like a set of lorum ipsum paragraph to repeat itself three times.

Or another example would be to repeat a block of placeholder images 9 times to demonstrate grids.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve such features with simple ruby eg:

```
- 20.times do |ntime|
  %h2 title
  %p text
```

..and you can help yourself with some nice available plugins!

**Text & data:** [faker](https://github.com/stympy/faker) ([here](https://github.com/stympy/faker/tree/master/lib/faker)'s a list of what can be done)

eg.

```
%h2 Name
= Faker::Name.name

%h2 Some text
%p
  = Faker::Lorem.paragraph(3)
```

**Images:** [placeholdit](https://github.com/ohokay/placeholdit)

eg.

```
%p
  my image:
  = placeholdit_image_tag "500"
```